# convert System.String to MultiValuedProperty

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a user execution script to prompt for users and feed them to another command using a variable.
Something like this:

```
$owners  = Read-Host
$members = Read-Host

New-DistributionGroup -Name test -ManagedBy $owners -Members $members
```

The problem is that `Read-Host` provides a typename of `System.String` and the `-ManagedBy` and `-Members` switches require a MultiValuedProperty.
I've tried doing an export of the `System.String` to CSV, but it doesn't break up the multiple values even if they are separated by a comma.

I know if I just populate a CSV and do an import it will work but I am distributing this script to branch offices and I need them to have as few steps as possible.

Answer (score 1):

So if the string they provide is a comma delimited string you can do something like.

```
$owners = (Read-host).Split(',')
```

Much the same for members...

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate your quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

"Multi-valued property" just means that you can provide multiple values (i.e. an array) as the argument to the parameter. If your users input something like

```
alice@example.com,bob@example.com,charlie@example.com
```

you need to split the (comma-separated) string to get an actual array:

```
$owners  = $owners -split ' *, *'
$members = $members -split ' *, *'
```

The expression `*, *` will also take care of spaces that the user may have put before and/or after the separating commas.